# How to Deserialize List of Objects from API in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: api, .net-core

I am building an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application that calls a .NET 6 API. The API I am trying to call returns a list of DTO's.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<RaceDTO>>> GetRaces()
{
    var races = await _repository.GetAllRaces();
    var record = _mapper.Map<List<RaceDTO>>(races);

    return Ok(record);
}
```

When I attempt to call my API from the ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller, I can see that I'm hitting the API, but I am not deserializing the list properly.

This is what my API is sending:

[image]

This is my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller making the API call and trying to deserialize my list of races:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
            "https://localhost:7252/api/Race")
            {
                Headers =
                    {
                        { HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json" },
                        { HeaderNames.UserAgent, "Capstone MVC" }
                    }
            };

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using var contesntStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        Races = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<RaceDTO>>(contesntStream);
    }

    return View(Races);
}
```

This is what I get when deserializing the result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the _mapper doing? Are you sure you are hitting the right api? In your image, the method ends with `return NotFound(...)` but in your posted code the method ends with `return Ok(...)` ... so not sure why these are not the same.

Comment: The _mapper is in the api. It converts the list of entities(in this case list of the entity race) and turns it into a list of race dto's. I am hitting the api i can see it when i set a breakpoint. The first screenshot shows what the api is returning. The second screenshot is in the MVC controller where it is attempting to make a call to that api and the deserialize the response.

Comment: Okay so why is the code in the (first) screenshot not the same as the posted code (so far as I can tell - based on what I stated in my previous comment)?

Comment: The code in the first screenshot is showing the api endpoint. It is just there to show that the api should return a list of races. Maybe by putting it here I am making the post confusing. The api is returning a result which is what the first screen shot shows. The mvc application which is the second screen shot is calling that api. I am hitting the api however I am having trouble deserializing the result. If you look in the second screenshot it shows I have two results but it is all null.

Comment: I'm just confused. Your screenshot (image) of the endpoint does not seem to match the code you posted which is supposed to be the endpoint. Do you understand what I am saying? Also when I look closer - the endpoint you posted code for is called `GetRaces` but the endpoint you actually call is called `Race`. I don't think you are calling the endpoint you think you are calling.

Comment: Ignore the first screenshot and first code snippet. They are purely to show that the api i am calling is being reached and sending data. The issue is in the second snippet i am trying to deserialize the response and i am not showing any data. The weird part is if you zoom in on the screenshot you can see that it shows two records but noting inside of the records.